# Why windows forms application could stuck in user32!__ClientWaitMessageExMPH?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winapi, message-pump

I have multithreaded .net 4 windows forms application, that sometimes just stop to answer to user actions and Invoke() calls.

I have made a dump during this hang, and seems that main thread is blocked inside of waiting for user input.

Here is stack trace for main thread: http://pastebin.com/dVee3T0N

Why did it suck there, and could I lock something, that can be used in message pump, I did not lock any of native things directly.

After hang began - CPU usage of main thread is zero.

Comment: Do you have some specific requirements to make Invoke calls (like using return value or output parameters)? If not, replace Invoke by BeginInvoke, this may help. BeginInvoke should be default choice.

Comment: Unfortunately, it will break application logic in many places.

Comment: Do you have some Wait operations in main thread?

Comment: Application also refuses to process BeginInvoke

Comment: Alex Farber, no, I don`t do that. And by call stack we can see, that proccess`s waiting is caused by system libraries.

Comment: A Winforms program that uses multiple UI threads is practically guaranteed to deadlock.  Best way to trigger it is by locking the work station.  That usually causes the SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged event to fire.  Lots of controls subscribe that event so they can redraw themselves.  SystemEvents makes an effort to raise the event on the UI thread of a program, when there is more than one of them then it has no hope.  Deadlock is the inevitable outcome.  Completely undebuggable as well, the actual deadlock occurs in kernel mode code which you can't see.

Comment: I have only one UI thread.